# @HTML extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I will keep things simple.

I have the following model :

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

I created this partial view for this model in ..\Shared\DisplayTemplates\Person.cshtml

```
@model BillSplitter.Classes.Person
<b>@Model.FullName</b>
```

In a view, the following code works great:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PaidBy) //PaidBy is type of Person
```

Here's the extension I would like to create:

```
public static IHtmlString DisplayPersons(this HtmlHelper helper, IEnumerable<Person> model)
{
    string htmlString = "";
    foreach (Person p in model)
       string += helper.DisplayFor(p); //PROBLEM!

    return new HtmlString(htmlString);
}
```

The problem is helper does not expose the `DisplayFor` function.

What can I do to get the `HtmlString` from my partial view in this extension?

Comment: `using System.Web.Mvc.Html`, though you don't have to do that--MVC will know how to handle an `IEnumerable<T>`. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a collection of `Person` to `@Html.DisplayFor`, it will automatically iterate over it and display each `Person` using the right template :

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PersonList)
```

Assuming that `PersonList` is an `IEnumerable<Person>`, each `Person` will be displayed according to your `DisplayTemplate`, which is what you're trying to achieve with your custom HtmlHelper extension.